# 90s/2000s book with space soldier is fighting rebels. Then joins rebels who have alien tech

Tags: story-identification, books

The book's story as far as I can remember is, space soldiers are fighting with bio mech suits against rebels (they are inside these suits and apparently there is a lot of bio gel).

One soldier defects to the rebels who have alien tech. They implant alien tech into him as well and together they go searching for the creators of the alien tech. They find the alien who tells them that the tech they have is not important to it... keep thinking this tech may be alive and be an "egg", not sure I remember clearly.

Read the book in the late 90's early 2000's.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect this is [*Fallen Dragon*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/45258.Fallen_Dragon#) (2001) by Peter F. Hamilton. Goodreads summary:

> Deploying invulnerable twenty-fifth-century soldiers called Skins, Zantiu-Braun's corporate starships loot entire planets. But as the Skins invade bucolic Thallspring, Z-B's strategy is about to go awry, all because of: Sgt. Lawrence Newton, a dreamer whose twenty years as a Skin have destroyed his hopes and desires; Denise Ebourn, a school teacher and resistance leader whose guerrilla tactics rival those of Che Guevara and George Washington and Simon Roderick, the director who serves Z-B with a dedication that not even he himself can understand. Grimly determined to steal, or protect, a mysterious treasure, the three players engage in a private war that will explode into unimaginable quests for personal grace...or galactic domination

Protagonist is a corporate soldier who wears 'Skin' - biomechanical armour, with gel used on the skin to facilitate putting it on.

The alien is a 'dragon' and described as looking like an egg. It has produced advanced tech for the rebels, but is not interested in developing any kind of industrial base in its own right.